# Are there any practical reasons to use `-include` in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, include, gnu-make

I was recently debugging a vague problem which turned out to be caused by a misplaced sub-Makefile which was *conditionally* included into a main Makefile by the `-include` directive. Mind the starting minus sign. According to GNU Make [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html):

> If you want make to simply ignore a makefile which does not exist or
>   cannot be remade, with no error message, use the `-include` directive
>   instead of include, like this:
>
> ```
> -include filenames…
> ```
>
> This acts like include in every way except that there is no error (not
>   even a warning) if any of the filenames (or any prerequisites of any
>   of the filenames) do not exist or cannot be remade.
>
> For compatibility with some other make implementations, `sinclude` is
>   another name for `-include`.

The nastiest problem with this directive is that no diagnostics whatsoever are given when the sub-Makefile cannot be found. Needless to say, this complicates debugging a lot.

In fact, there was no real need to use it there, a regular `include` worked just fine and is much more robust. I understand the original author's intention for using `-include`. That sub-Makefile contained some "secret" stuff that was not meant to be shared with 3rd party engineers. But this functionality was never used in the end, and it could have been implemented in a more transparent way.

I wonder if there are other practical cases when `-include` is useful. Maybe some cases when one or several makefiles are dynamically generated during the build process?

Comment: If the sub-makefile was essential (such that its absence caused a problem), then `-include` was the wrong tool for the job. If the goal was to provide 3rd-party engineers a makefile that *worked* but not give them the secret stuff, then the makefile was faulty. Had the makefile been written correctly, `-include` would have been exactly the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely, the most useful application of `-include` is when the include file is auto-generated by make itself.

Remember that all include files also become make's targets automatically. So `-include generated_file` does not make make to fail prematurely, but implies that `generated_file` will be (re-)built using other rules in the current Makefile. This can be exploited in auto-dependencies generation, for example.

BTW. Another trick with 'include' is that `include $(empty_var)` also works without errors (i.e. is no-op).

Comment: This trick shouldn't be necessary with newer versions of GNU make.  It will defer complaining about non-existing makefiles until after it determines that they can't be remade, even if you use `include`.

Comment: "Remember that all include files also become make's targets automatically". This is something I've never given a thought, but it makes sense after you've mentioned it.